# Difficulty in deploying ML model to Heroku

Tags: python, github, machine-learning, heroku

Any help would be much appreciated. I created a repository [here](https://github.com/srdasara/Deploying_ML_CarPricePrediction) where all files are linked. I'm currently trying to learn how to deploy an ML model to Heroku. This is a pretty simple model and I was following along with a YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_tpQSY1aTs). When I run 'python app.py' on my terminal, the local server does run correctly, showing the exact interface I want.

When trying to deploy it on Heroku, I linked my GitHub repository and selected 'Deploy Branch'; Here, Heroku states that the app was successfully deployed. HOWEVER, when I then try to view, a page comes up stating Application Error.

As mentioned, I'm really not sure what's going wrong and would appreciate any guidance to get this working – I'd like to deploy other ML models I've been working on and getting this preliminary one running would be a huge help. Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: "Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500 ("application error")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have forgotten to create the `Procfile`. This is necessary for Heroku as it tells Heroku how to startup your application on it's servers.

Since you're server file is `app.py` and the Flask app is `app` as well, the following would be the contents of the `Procfile`

`web: gunicorn app:app`

Also update your `requirements.txt` file by adding gunicorn, as an example what i had was
`gunicorn==20.1.0`

For more information about the `Procfile` see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

I have deployed this personally and it works fine now

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your response! I added the Procfile as mentioned but still no luck... could it be something wrong with the requirements.txt file, or am I missing anything else?

Comment: Hi, please add gunicorn into the requirements file as well, i will edit this response